# Why does the measure of a set not specify any units?

Tags: measure-theory

Coming from an engineering background, I find that measures of objects are numerical. For eg. the measure of a line is its length and that of a plane is its area and so on. But why leave out the units? So a line of length 1 and a square of area 1 have the same measure ? What distinguishes the measure of objects in different dimensions?

Comment: Math doesn't really have units at all. Units are physical.

Comment: So how to differentiate objects with same measure? or is there no need for such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, can you show me an area of pure math that uses things like meters? Units are physical.

A unit line, square, and cube all have the same measure in the sense that it's $1$. A line, square, and cube do NOT all have the same measure in the sense that the function $\mu_1$ $\mu_2$ and $\mu_3$ (Lebesgue measures in 1,2,3 dimensions) are different.

You *can* attach units to a measure but the issue is now you're talking about this in a certain context.

For example what is the probability of picking a number from the interval $[0,1]$ that is in the interval $[0,.5]$? Well that is $.5$. This is a measure. I am NOT talking about $.5$ feet, I mean the *probability* is $.5$. I can also talk about something being $.5$ feet, or meters or whatever! The point of math is **generalization**. We want things to be as general as possible.

Can you handle graphing the function $y=2x$ without knowing what $x$ and $y$ are? Then you can handle this!

Lets be more rigorous. A measure space is a triple, $(X,F, \mu)$. $X$ is a set, $F$ is a collection of subsets to take the measure of, and $\mu$ is the measure.

So your question is, how do we differentiate between squares and lines? Well it's all summed up in $X, F, \mu$. For example, in 2 dimensions the square has measure $1$ while the line has measure 0 and the cube doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I am new to pure maths and that's the cause of the confusion. Your example is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: To be honest, measures as in probability still can be thought as of units when comes from physical background. That is, $p =0.5$ is unitless since it can be thought of $0.5\mathrm m/ 1 \mathrm m$. I think the trick is that measure theory was introduced not to serve subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ where you can think of units (even though it comes with some issues over fractals), but over general spaces, where even the notion of dimension (related to units) makes no sense.